# Python Excel package win32com.client doesn't save the file without throwing any error

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm trying to run some code in Python that opens some .xlsm file (out2.xlsm) and saves it after inserting VBA code under a new name 'output.xlsm'. So I run the code, it gives no error but when I check the folder, there is no file named 'output.xlsm', so it doesn't actually save it apparently.

I've tried so many things but can't seem to figure this out. What can be the reason? The interesting thing is that I have used exactly the same code for some time and it was working — it was saving the file when I run the code. But now somehow it doesn't save the file, I didn't change anything at all in the code. My suspicion is maybe I change something in the Excel programm, some kind of settings maybe?

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r"C:/Users/nnn/Desktop/project3/out2.xlsm")
excel.Visible = False

excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
excelModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
excel.Application.Run(myMacroName)
excel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs('output.xlsm')
excel.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=True)
excel.Application.Quit()
del excel
```

Comment: Please post the VBA module you are attempting to add. Also, you should be wrapping all these COM processing in `try...except...finally` to properly clean up background process, error or not.

Comment: I think there is an `output.xlsm`. You will probably find it in your **default documents** folder not the folder that the python file is located in. Like you have with the input file, set the full path for the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `SaveAs` without specifying the full path will save the file in the current folder, whatever that happens to be. Always specify full path name:

```
excel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs('C:/Users/nnn/Desktop/project3/output.xlsm')
```